# How to read CSV of JSON strings in R

Tags: r

I have a file which consists different JSON strings in rows, the format of this file is CSV, I want to import all these JSON strings into R but unable to find a successful way, I want to avoid solutions where i have to convert csv into a JSON first.

1. {"color":"Black","size":"","material":"Georgette","occasion":"Party","rise":"","length":"","pattern":"Embroidered","sleeve":"","neck_type":"","fit":"","bra_type":"","wiring":"","color_filter":"Black","type_filter":"Semi-Stitched","gender":"Women","designed_by":"","article_identifier_type":"","article_identification_value":"","product_dimension":""}

2.{"color":"Blue","size":"","material":"Georgette","occasion":"Party","rise":"","length":"","pattern":"Embroidered","sleeve":"","neck_type":"","fit":"","bra_type":"","wiring":"","color_filter":"Blue","type_filter":"Semi-Stitched","gender":"Women","designed_by":"","article_identifier_type":"","article_identification_value":"","product_dimension":""}

3.{"color":"White","size":"","material":"Cotton","occasion":"Ethnic","rise":"","length":"","pattern":"Embroidered","sleeve":"","neck_type":"","fit":"","bra_type":"","wiring":"","color_filter":"White","type_filter":"With Blouse","gender":"Women","designed_by":"","article_identifier_type":"","article_identification_value":"","product_dimension":""}

4.
{"color":"Blue","size":"","material":"Georgette","occasion":"Party","rise":"","length":"","pattern":"Embroidered","sleeve":"","neck_type":"","fit":"","bra_type":"","wiring":"","color_filter":"Blue","type_filter":"Semi-Stitched","gender":"Women","designed_by":"","article_identifier_type":"","article_identification_value":"","product_dimension":""}

5.{"color":"Turquoise","size":"","material":"Cotton","occasion":"Party","rise":"","length":"","pattern":"Floral Print","sleeve":"","neck_type":"","fit":"","bra_type":"","wiring":"","color_filter":"Turquoise","type_filter":"Semi-Stitched","gender":"Women","designed_by":"","article_identifier_type":"","article_identification_value":"","product_dimension":""}

Comment: Hi @Vaibhav, can you show  some sample data?

Comment: Are the "1." and "2." bits in the file? Because if they are then this isn't a particularly good-looking CSV or JSON file.

Comment: What have (if anything) have you tried so far that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the format of this file is semicolon separated CSV, this may be work :

```
require(jsonlite)


# Importing CSV 
my_data <- read.csv2("data.csv", sep = ";", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "") #keep quotes


# Transform JSON into a list
my_data.list <- lapply(my_data$V1, function(x) fromJSON(x))


# Transform into DF
my_data.df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(my_data.list, as.data.frame))
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: I tried what you suggested above but the rows are different from what they should be.

Comment: my_data[1,][1] "\"{\"\"color\"\":\"\"Black\"\",\"\"size\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"material\"\":\"\"Georgette\"\",\"\"occasion\"\":\"\"Party\"\",\"\"rise\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"length\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"pattern\"\":\"\"Embroidered\"\",\"\"sleeve\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"neck_type\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"fit\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"bra_type\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"wiring\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"color_filter\"\":\"\"Black\"\",\"\"type_filter\"\":\"\"Semi-Stitched\"\",\"\"gender\"\":\"\"Women\"\",\"\"designed_by\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"article_identifier_type\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"article_identification_value\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"product_dimension\"\":\"\"\"\"}\""

Comment: Some how "\" is introduced every here and there, How should i remove these.

Comment: When you remove quote = "", does it work ?  like : my_data <- read.csv2("data.csv", sep = ";", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F) #keep quotes